# How to connect PyMongo with uppercase host name?

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

I tried to connect Pymongo with the uppercase hostname, but it automatically converting to lowercase? Is there any way to connect with the uppercase hostname?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

MongoClient("MONGO_1")
```

Output

> MongoClient(host=['mongo_1:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True)

Here My app and mongo db are running on docker container. App container name is APP_1 and mongodb container name is MONGO_1. And both containers are in a same docker network. So here the host name will be container name and it is uppercase.

Comment: Hostnames are (usually - there are special cases) not case sensitive; why is this an issue?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am using docker with docker network. So the hostname will be the name of the docker container. In my case, the container name is uppercase letters as shown in the code snippet. Docker network is strictly case sensitive, So now not able to connect the mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames are not case sensitive.

The driver can perform case-insensitive comparisons on the hostnames, preserving input case, or it can lowercase (or uppercase) all of the hostnames.

Additionally if you are connecting to a replica set, the driver will use hostnames as defined in replica set configuration (potentially preserving *that* case).

Comment: Hi, In my case I am using dockers. So mongo is only accessible through the docker container name. and the docker container name is case sensitive. Here hostname is case sensitive.

Comment: If you have some references to back this up add them to the question, otherwise you probably misunderstood something.